# Distance between two Geo Location in feet

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, geolocation, geometry

How to find difference between two location in different units.I already found the way to calculate it in kilometers and miles but not sure about feet.

```
private double Distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, int unit) 
    {  
      double theta = lon1 - lon2;  
      double dist = Math.Sin(Deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(Deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(Deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(Deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(Deg2rad(theta));  
      dist = Math.Acos(dist);  
      dist = Rad2deg(dist);  
      dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;  
      if (unit == GeoFence.RadiusUnits.Kilometers.GetHashCode()) 
      {  
        dist = dist * 1.609344;  //kilometers
      } 
      else if (unit ==  GeoFence.RadiusUnits.Feet.GetHashCode()) 
      {  
        //Here I need to calculate distance in feet
      } 
      return (dist);  //By default the distance is in statute miles 
    }
```

And I am not sure about the logic behind **1.609344** to calculate it in kilometers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dist` seems to be the distance in miles.

1 mile   is  1.609344 km(or  5280ft), so you must multliply `dist` by 5280

```
  else if (unit ==  GeoFence.RadiusUnits.Feet.GetHashCode()) 
  {  
    dist = dist * 5280;
  }
```